# Macro to copy as values distinct values from one Excel tab to another

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have an excel workbook with a macro that does almost everything I want it to do. This macro copies data from a range on one tab, then pastes the distinct values on another tab.

What I need help with is changing the macro to paste as values. The data being copied is a formula and formatted differently than the destination.

The below macro is based off the one **Gary's Student** was nice enough to create to answer the question at this link:
[Macro to copy distinct values from one Excel sheet to another](https://superuser.com/questions/884115/macro-to-copy-distinct-values-from-one-excel-sheet-to-another/1494558#1494558)

```
Sub Update()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Set s1 = Sheets("Copy Tab")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Paste Tab")
    s1.Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Copy s2.Range("A9")
    s2.Range("A8:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

Comment: You could look into [PasteSpecial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial) or you could try the ["transfer method"](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/best-way-to-copy-pastespecial-values-only-with-vba) (just one example; there are a dozen different ways to 'copy' by setting values of ranges without using the Copy method)

Answer (score 1):

Change the Copy line:

> `s1.Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Copy s2.Range("A9")`

To equate the values:

```
s2.Range("A9").Resize(s1.Cells(s1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row-1).Value = s1.Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Value
```

Now we avoid the clipboard and we only move the values.

Comment: Thank you for the attempt. Unfortunately, each time I run this, I do not get all the distinct values and the last being a #N/A. There are no #N/A's in the data the column being pulled.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is record a new macro, then perform the action once manually, stop the recording and look at the new macro that was recorded. It will tell you exactly what code to use.

Why do I tell you the above? It will help you become a good VBA developer without having to search the whole internet for every bit of code.

If you do the above, you'll see that you get the following macro:

```
Range("A8").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

So your code becomes:

```
Sub Update()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Set s1 = Sheets("Copy Tab")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Paste Tab")
    s1.Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Copy s2.Range("A9")

    s2.Range("A8:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: I am new to VBA. However, trying to use parts of a recorded macro was the 1st thing I did. Maybe I missed something what combining or maybe I put it in the wrong place. Please try not to assume. It made your post sound condescending.

Comment: I'm sorry. That was not at all my intention. Most people do not know you can record macro's at all and when you point that out, a whole world opens up. I write my answer not just to the person who posts the question, but every next person who googles it and finds this answer. I tried to write it as helpful as possible. I'm sorry you didn't feel that way. Any wordings I can change to improve?

Comment: Thank you for your attempt. Unfortunately, this pulls Run-Time Error 1004 "PasteSpecial method of Range class failed. Thank you for trying.

Comment: Good point on your reply. I probably did rush to judgement.

Comment: Weird that it is not working on your end. Did you copy both the s2.Range(...).Select and the Selection code? Both need to be used because you first make a selection and then paste into it.

Comment: @Bob if you didn't say in your question that you tried something, it's not exactly fair to bristle when folks assume you didn't try it. Check out [How To Ask a Good Question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm missing something, but it seems pretty straight forward.

If you split you copy row and use  PasteSpecial, I don't see why it wouldn't work.

```
s1.Range("B2:B" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Copy s2.Range("A9")
```

turns into

```
s1.Range("B2:B" & s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
s2.Range("A9").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

This does essentially the same thing as Scott Craner's answer, but uses the cut copy.
If you modify his answer to:

```
Sub Update()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Set s1 = Sheets("Copy Tab")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Paste Tab")
    s2.Range("A9").Resize(s1.Cells(s1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row - 1).Value = s1.Range("B2:B" & s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Value
    s2.Range("A8:A40").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

Does it work better?